# Google Analytics: How to display traffic data of all my sites as one graf?

Tags: graph, google-analytics, web-traffic

As a webmaster I support N different client sites. How to display all their traffic data at one joint graph conveniently?

Answer (score 0):

If "n" is something in the hundreds or thousands you can use the recently announced [APIs for Large Companies](http://analytics.blogspot.de/2013/10/new-google-analytics-apis-for-large.html).

If your needs are somewhat smaller you can pull the data into a Google spreadsheet (via Google apps script) and use the Chart functions (or Google Charts) to create a combined graph.